# Update to Android 4.2 disappeared after factory reset

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, factory-reset

My Galaxy SII recently updated to Android 4.2. I then had to reset to factory settings and the update has disappeared. If I search for updates, a message comes up saying the latest updates have already been installed. Can I get this back somehow??

Answer (score 1):

Check Android version. You're already at Android 4.2. Resetting to factory setting won't reset it to earlier Android version.

Comment: Well, that's my point - it has. Maybe I got this wrong in my description, though - I'm talking about the update to 4.2 Jelly Bean. It's just not there anymore.

Comment: If you go to *Settings->About phone*, what Android version does it report to be installed on the device?

Comment: A factory reset on and Android device is really not the same as a factory reset on like a computer. Really a factory reset on an android device just restores the original apps on the phone and whips your user data and settings. It does not clear out system updates. You are still running android 4.2 most likely.